# inconsistent appearance of Horizon dashboard!

Tags: openstack

Succeeded deployment of a multi node installation of OpenStack, :) BUT, still have this 'inconsistent' appearance of Horizon dashboard .. :(

(I've resolved an "Internal Server Error" before, related to the Apache2 and the wsgi module ..)

Any help please?

*OpenStack version: OCATA

[image: Horizon/Dashboard -Click here-]

Answer (score 1):

*Problem found* : **Django Compressor Not Regenerating Compressed CSS**

the directory '/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/static/scss' is **empty**, while ''/var/lib/openstack-dashboard/static/js' **contains** .js files.

Still searching for a solution !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can regenerate and compress the files under assets using

```
/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py collectstatic --noinput 
/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/manage.py compress
```